# How to get disk model and serial number for the disk Windows is installed on

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, c++, c

You can use `wmic diskdrive get model,serialnumber` to get the **model** and the **serial number** of the disks currently plugged in, which are unique if you use both of them (if you use only serial number, there may be a change that another manufactured used the same one, even tho in practice they all have a different pattern), which is really useful if you need a way to uniquely difference two devices (PC, laptops...). Now the problem that I have is that I only want the model and serial number of the disk that the OS is installed on.

Is there another command or a combination of them (checking the results of them and maybe seeing a common part which will lead to what I need), that will return  the values only for the one with the OS installed on?

I checked the options for `wmic diskdrive get` and I didn't see one that will do what I need. Also there is `vol C`, but that gives a serial number given by Windows to that logical volume (partition), not the serial number of the disk itself.

Also, while it is true that the user can simply install the OS on a different disk and so the model and the serial number would be different from last time (in case they even realize that is the verification method), the time it takes to do that (be it cloning or clean install and then download and install the app again), at least for my use case, is enough of an inconvenience to try and trick the app, and also it is used for some other minor verification that can't be tied to the IP as that one can easily be changed with a router restart or network disable/enable (most of the times), but also the IP is for the whole network, not a device in particularly.

//Edit1: I found another command which works when used with Windows 11 **Terminal**/**PowerShell**, but unfortunately when used in C++ like this `system("Get-Disk (Get-Partition -DriveLetter 'C').DiskNumber");` it gives the error `'Get-Disk' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` Because I need only for Windows, and by default it is going to use partition C, this would have been it. It gives the following info `Number / Friendly Name (is the manufacturer and model) / Serial Number / Health Status / Operational Status / Total Size / Partition Style`.

//Edit2: Using the commands Zac67 gave I tried them in C++ (std17, release x64, I need only Windows):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

std::string exec(const char* cmd) {
    std::array<char, 128> buffer;
    std::string result;
    std::unique_ptr<FILE, decltype(&_pclose)> pipe(_popen(cmd, "r"), _pclose);
    if (!pipe) {
        throw std::runtime_error("popen() failed!");
    }
    while (fgets(buffer.data(), buffer.size(), pipe.get()) != nullptr) {
        result += buffer.data();
    }
    return result;
}

void main() {
    cout << exec("wmic bootconfig get description");
    cout << exec("wmic diskdrive where DeviceID='\\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE3' get model,serialnumber");
}
```

The first command has the return I was expecting: `Description\Device\Harddisk3\Partition1`, but when the second command is ran, unfortunately I get `ERROR: Description = Invalid query`.
If I run them straight in CMD then both of them are running fine, but if I'm using them in Windows 11 Terminal/PowerShell then same as with the code, the first one is fine, but the same error with the second command.

//Edit3: Based on the commands I got from Zac67, this is the final form in C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>

std::string exec(const char* cmd) {
    std::array<char, 128> buffer;
    std::string result;
    std::unique_ptr<FILE, decltype(&_pclose)> pipe(_popen(cmd, "r"), _pclose);
    if (!pipe) {
        throw std::runtime_error("popen() failed!");
    }
    while (fgets(buffer.data(), buffer.size(), pipe.get()) != nullptr) {
        result += buffer.data();
    }
    return result;
}

void replaceString(std::string& subject, const std::string& search,
    const std::string& replace) {
    size_t pos = 0;
    while ((pos = subject.find(search, pos)) != std::string::npos) {
        subject.replace(pos, search.length(), replace);
        pos += replace.length();
    }
}

void main() {
    std::string index = exec("wmic bootconfig get description");
    index = index.at(index.find_last_of("\\") - 1);
    std::string modelSerialNumber = "wmic diskdrive where DeviceID='\\\\\\\\.\\\\PHYSICALDRIVE" + index + "' get model,serialnumber";
    modelSerialNumber = exec(modelSerialNumber.c_str());
    replaceString(modelSerialNumber, "Model", "");
    replaceString(modelSerialNumber, "SerialNumber", "");
    replaceString(modelSerialNumber, " ", "");
    std::cout << modelSerialNumber;
}
```

The output will be: `KINGSTONSA2000M8250GXXXX_XXXX_XXXX_XXXX_XXXX_XXXX_XXXX_XXXX.`. For my use case I needed the model and the serial number united like that.

Comment: [smartmontools](https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/Download#InstalltheWindowspackage) for Windows: `smartctl -a /dev/<disk>` _(linux path of `/dev/<sda||sdb||etc>` remains the correct syntax)_. If you only wanted those two specific details returned, a simple script could be written to parse out those two specific lines, `Device Model:` and `Serial Number:`

Comment: Because the app is going to be installed on clients devices, I don't want to have to also install other 3rd party software/libraries at least for this use case to avoid future licensing problems. I did see that this is open source now, but you never know what will change in the future. Even tho I don't want to use it, thanks for the suggestion and your time!

Comment: Re Edit2: you need to escape meta characters properly for the language you use. C++ doesn't require CMD's ridiculous double \\ escape, so just remove every other backslash. Still, you should use native WMI queries inside C++ instead of running external commands.

Comment: I did try `exec("wmic diskdrive where DeviceID='\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE3' get model,serialnumber");` but I was getting the same error. I'll look for some examples with native wmi queries, if that is the normal way to actually do it. I'm normally a Java programmer, and some parts of C++ are making my head spin. The code is more "raw" then how it is in Java.

Comment: It turns out I had to actually use `exec("wmic diskdrive where DeviceID='\\\\\\\\.\\\\PHYSICALDRIVE3' get model,serialnumber");` (so many \ ) for that to work. I'm still looking for native wmi queries, but at least if I'm not going to find a way, I have this method that is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run

```
C:\> wmic bootconfig get description
Description
\Device\Harddisk3\Partition2
```

Note the index following *Harddisk* - here *3*. That's the index used in the next query.

Run

```
C:\> wmic diskdrive where DeviceID='\\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE3' get model,serialnumber
Model                    SerialNumber
Samsung SSD 980 PRO 1TB  00xx_xxxx_xxxx_xxxx.
```

The doubled `\\` are necessary to escape each `\` for cmd batch. If you run the same logic in another language you should only need `\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE3`. Of course, you should prefer native WMI queries in C++.

Comment: "Note the 3 from \Device\Harddisk3\Partition2." I take it that the 3 is the index as when you run `wmic diskdrive get model,serialnumber,index`? And for example if a user only has one disk, then `wmic bootconfig get description` would return `\Device\Harddisk0\PartitionX` (is the number after Partition the number of partitions for that disk or what else?), so you'll now need to use `wmic diskdrive where DeviceID='\\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE0' get model,serialnumber`? In my case, the SSD with the OS also has index 3, and so I don't want to confuse that with something else.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Get the index from the first query, use the index in the second query for the desired boot disk.

Comment: That is exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: So, when I was testing I opened CMD, and there they were working, but now I moved to C++ (std17) to implement it, and while `wmic bootconfig get description` does give the result I was expecting, `wmic diskdrive where DeviceID='\\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE3' get model,serialnumber` returns `ERROR: Description = Invalid query` the same as when running it in Terminal/PowerShell. See Edit2 in main post for code.

Comment: I'll mark this as the answer as technically those are the commands I needed, and added in Edit3 the code that is now working, but with cmd. I looked into native wmi c++ but it is too much work for just this, so I'll stick with this form. Thank you again!